# How do I call a method if the data appears on the screen (vue)?

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, vue-component, loading, vuetify.js

My case like this :

If I search a data, it will show all data doctor. But for available day, I want to make it separately. when finished displaying all the doctor's data. I want to call the available method for async or call api to display available day. This available day is run when doctor data appears on the screen. So when the doctor's data appears on the screen, it will call available day. If the user scrolls down, it will call available day from another doctor

My code like this :

```
<v-col
v-for="(item, i) in items"
:key="i"
cols="12"
>
    <v-card
        dark
    >
        <div class="d-flex flex-no-wrap justify-space-between">
        <div>
            <v-card-title
            class="headline"
            v-text="item.doctor"
            ></v-card-title>

            <v-card-subtitle v-text="item.hospital"></v-card-subtitle>
            <v-card-subtitle>Available today</v-card-subtitle>
        </div>

        <v-avatar
            class="ma-3"
            size="125"
            tile
        >
            <v-img :src="item.src"></v-img>
        </v-avatar>
        </div>
    </v-card>
</v-col>
```

Demo and full code like this : https://codepen.io/trendingnews/pen/ZEYpBeW?editors=1010

My problem is
If I display all the doctor's data, for example 50 data, it's very fast. only 2-3 seconds

But if I display all the doctor's data and available days, for example 50 data, it's very slow. around 10 seconds

So for available day, I want to make it separate. It's only called when the doctor's data appears on the screen

Doctor data and available day are different API. So this is my problem. I have to handle this from the front end

How can I do that? Is there a package that can help? I have used vuex store in this project

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for an Intersection Observer library to do things when the doctor is scrolled to on the screen?  If that's the case, I would look at things like [vue-observe-visibility](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-observe-visibility) or [vue-intersect](https://github.com/heavyy/vue-intersect).

Comment: @StevenB. is that really suitable for my case? my case like this. when loaded the first time it will display all the doctor's data. but for available day of each doctor's, it will be called when the doctor appears on the screen when the user scrolls down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet that loads data using the **vue-observe-visibility** plugin (https://github.com/Akryum/vue-observe-visibility):

1. The app loads data from a mockup source
2. A placeholder/preloader shows that something is happening
3. When the data downloads (after coming into view) the preloader disappears

Pay attention to the parameters of the **v-observe-visibility**: you have to pass down some ID (custom parameter), you should do it only once (`once: true`), and you may want some throttling on it.

**NOTE:** the downloaded data in this snippet is so small, that you may miss the "downloading" state - scroll down fast to the end (there are a 100 posts in the list)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    posts: []
  },
  methods: {
    fetchPosts(id) {
      return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id ? id : ''}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => json)
    },
    async visibilityChanged(isVisible, entry, id) {
      const post = await this.fetchPosts(id)
      Vue.set(this.posts.find(e => e.id === id), 'body', post.body)
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    const data = await this.fetchPosts()
    // this is only for the mockup data: I pluck the id and title,
    // so the body can be downloaded later
    this.posts = data.map(e => ({
      id: e.id,
      title: e.title
    }))
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-observe-visibility/dist/vue-observe-visibility.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-row v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id" v-observe-visibility="{
          callback: (isVisible, entry) => visibilityChanged(isVisible, entry, post.id),
          once: true,
          throttle: 100
        }">
        <v-col>
          <v-row>
            <v-col>
              <b>{{post.title}}</b>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col>
              <v-progress-circular indeterminate color="primary" v-if="!post.body"></v-progress-circular>
              {{post.body}}
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: is that really suitable for my case? I have implemented it in my case. but there seemed to be a lot of async happening. when i type something in the input text, it will be async. when I scroll down, it will also be async

Comment: @SuccessMan downloading data from an external API will always be asynchronous. If the response arrives slowly (slower than you need/want), you have to investigate the reason behind it being slow.

Comment: yes.  but it looks like repeating async.  if an id is already asynch, there is no need to asynch anymore.  other than that when I type in input text, it's automatically asych.  should not

Comment: @SuccessMan **once: true** ensures that it’s downloaded only once on visible. Otherwise you can add a check if the content is already downloaded in the **visibilityChanged** and/or the **fetchPosts**.

Comment: okay I will try to study this package in detail. btw is this package the only way to solve my problem? or is there another way?

Comment: even though your answer hasn't helped, I still accept your answer. I will try to study this package in detail