# How can I add new values to an array object of state using Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, multidimensional-array, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My code like this :

```
<template>
    ...

    ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
    ...
    methods: {
        ...mapActions([
            'getDataDoctor',
            'getDataSchedule'
        ]),
        async visibilityChanged(isVisible, entry, item) {
            let param = {
                hospitalId: item.hospital_id,
                doctorId: item.doctor_id
            }
            await this.getDataSchedule(param)
            let data = this.dataDoctor
            for (let key in data) {
                this.$set(data[key].find(e => e.doctor_id === item.doctor_id && e.hospital_id === item.hospital_id), 'schedule', this.dataSchedule.schedule)
            }
        }
    },
    computed: { 
        ...mapState({
            dataDoctor: state => state.dataStore.dataDoctor,
            dataSchedule: state => state.dataStore.dataSchedule
        }),
    },
}
</script>
```

If I console.log(this.dataDoctor), the result like this :

[image]

Or you can see the this.dataDoctor this : https://pastebin.com/yGjsTBjX

this.dataDoctor is state from vuex store. I want to add new value there. The name is schedule

I do like that. But there exist error like this :

Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: undefined

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'schedule' in undefined

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit looks wrong:

```js
for (let key in data) {
    this.$set(data[key].find(e => e.doctor_id === item.doctor_id && e.hospital_id === item.hospital_id), 'schedule', this.dataSchedule.schedule)
}
```

From the sample data you posted this will only find something for (at most) one value of `key`. For the other values of `key` the `find` will return `undefined` and the `$set` will fail.

Try this:

```js
for (const key in data) {
  const entry = data[key].find(e => e.doctor_id === item.doctor_id && e.hospital_id === item.hospital_id)

  console.log(`key is ${key}:`, entry)

  if (entry) {
    this.$set(entry, 'schedule', this.dataSchedule.schedule)
  }
}
```

Of course it is also possible that none of the entries will match. The console logging I've included should help you to identify that scenario too.

I should add that it is usually regarded as best practice to mutate store state within a store `mutation` rather than directly inside a component.

Comment: It works. But on the console exist error : `[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."` and `Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.`

Comment: apart from that it seems a lot of async is happening. when i scroll down, there is async on the console

Comment: @SuccessMan I assume you're using strict mode for the store? As I mentioned at the end of my answer you should really move these updates into store `mutations` rather than changing them directly in the component. That should resolve the strict mode warnings you are seeing.

Comment: I have done that and now there are no errors. but the problem is too much async. I have a search form. when I type something in the input text, it appears there is async. when i make a change in the console log appears async

Comment: @SuccessMan This is starting to feel like a chameleon question. Has the original question you asked been answered? If you have new questions I suggest you post them separately.

Comment: actually this question arises from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59331459/how-do-i-call-a-method-if-the-data-appears-on-the-screen-vue. it seems difficult to implement vue-observe-visibility in my case